# Customize Google Charts with CSS

Tags: css, charts, google-visualization

I want to customize the classes in Google Charts.

As far as I'm concerned, there are two options that I've stumbled upon. The first option is:

1. Just inspect the elements in the browser, to see what the name of the classes is, then just give them new rules in the css file. In some cases I've to set `!important;` to override the rule. This option seems very "ugly", because forcing the class to have an `!important;` state is just ugly.

> ```
> .charts-menu-button,
> .charts-menu-button-inner-box {
>     width: 200px;
>     line-height: 55px;
>     border: 0 !important;
>     padding: 0 !important;
> }
> ```

2. This is my second option which I'm pretty confused over. As I read the Google Chart docs, they suggest to call the "cssClass", like this:

> ```
> options: {
> ui: {
> cssClass: {}
>   }
> }
> ```

What I don't understand is when I'm going with the second option, absolute nothing happens to the class I want to customize.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong here, and is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the cssclassnames in options for the chart as below. Define the classes in the css file. Below example is for table chart.

```
chart1.options = {
    //      title: "User Chart",
            displayExactValues: true,
            'showRowNumber': false,
             'allowHtml': true, 
             is3D: true,
        //   'height' : '350px',
             cssClassNames : {
                 headerRow :'tableChartHeaderRow',
                 hoverTableRow : 'tableChartHeaderRowHighlightedState'
             }
         };
```

Comment: Not really following you here. Do you have the time and energy to make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/snz2bdcy/ Please check this. Please mark the answer as useful once you find the answer relevant

Comment: that's pretty much what I've done myself... but in some cases, I've had too override some rules with !important;

Comment: I think that won't be necessary. Please check all the css class names similar header row, etc. Try to provide styles this way, since using !important should be the last option. Else, try adding your own class on the classes for which you add important, if you can figure out where the classes are defined for the google charts.

Comment: yeah that's my point. You took the words right out of my mouth. How do I even know what all the class names are if I can't even find them? I hate using !important;... imo it's for the weak!

Comment: You would have got the answer. But, please find this reference. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table like tableRow, oddTableRow , hoverTableRow..

Comment: yeah... But I don't really use tables. I want to style/customize Googles date-range-filter. What I also notice is that the markup in the column-filter, like <div id="columnFilter_div"></div>, some markup are nested inside that div. But the rest of the markup, like the <ul><li></li></ul> ends up in the bottom of the page, before the closing body tag. That's really annoying...